# How can I click on a google map with capybara to create a marker

Tags: google-maps, capybara

I have a google map on a page.  User's can click on this map and it will drop a marker at that point.  How can I simulate this in Capybara?  It doesn't matter where they click as long as it's somewhere on the map.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [ActionBuilder](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html#click-instance_method) if you use Selenium driver. It will be something like:

```
within_frame(locator_of_frame_with_map) do
  map = find(locator_of_map).native
  page.driver.browser.action.move_to(map, x, y).click.perform
end
```

Code above is a draft. Obviously I can't provide working code without a demo.

Capybara itself doesn't have a cross-driver API for clicking at specific coordinates.

Comment: I could not get this to work with or without Selenium.  Also, I cannot use selenium driver since our CI server does not user Selenium

Answer (score 0):

with webkit driver in Capybara, I've used this:

```
javascript_to_trigger_click = <<-JS
$('#map > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1)').click();
JS
page.evaluate_script(javascript_to_trigger_click)
```

where `#map` is my element containing the google map.

Side note but I've lost so much time on this, be sure to enable whichever url capybara thread is running its test server into google console for your app. (you can see the url by setting `config.debug = true` for capybara)